Kafka UI message count
I am using kafka UI as a visual interface for viewing topics. I wanted to check if my service produced correct number of messages to the topic. When i used live mode in given topic i was able to confirm that 500 messages were produced (as expected) but when i go to overview of the topic. The total number always increased more than 500. Sometimes more than twice. I even checked on confluent and the total number of messages is same as kafka UI presents.
Any ideas where these differences come from ?
BR
Łukasz
